# Selecting employee based availability Query SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables, one for employees and another of their current and past activities. I need a function/query that selects an employee for the next activity based on type. here is sample data:

Table Employees

```
EmployeesID UserName    Type    Available
1           Bill    Clerical    1
2           Ann     Clerical    1
3           John    Technical   1
4           Jack    Technical   0
5           Mary    Clerical    0
6           Sam     Technical   0
7           Mark    Clerical    1
8           Andy    Clerical    1
9           Rick    Clerical    1
10          Nancy   Clerical    1
```

Activities

```
ActivityID  EmployeesID Status  Task_Datetime
101                2    Complete    6/11/2016 10:00
102                1    Complete    6/11/2016 10:12
103                3    Complete    6/11/2016 10:24
104                4    Complete    6/11/2016 10:36
105                7    Complete    6/11/2016 10:48
106                6    Complete    6/11/2016 11:00
107                5    Complete    6/11/2016 11:12
108                8    Complete    6/11/2016 11:24
109               10    Complete    6/11/2016 11:36
110                9    Complete    6/11/2016 11:48
111                5    Complete    6/11/2016 12:00
112                8    Complete    6/11/2016 12:12
113                3    Complete    6/11/2016 12:24
114                4    Complete    6/11/2016 12:36
115                1    Complete    6/11/2016 12:48
116                6    Complete    6/11/2016 13:00
117                7    Complete    6/11/2016 13:12
118                2    Complete    6/11/2016 13:24
119                9    Complete    6/11/2016 13:36
120               10    In Progress 6/11/2016 13:48
121                1    In Progress 6/11/2016 14:00
122                2    Complete    6/11/2016 14:12
123                3    Complete    6/11/2016 14:24
124                4    Complete    6/11/2016 14:36
125                6    In Progress 6/11/2016 14:48
```

Need to assign to available employee matching type without an activity in progress
if all are in progress, return 0
if more than one available, assign to the one that was assigned.

So if next assign is clerical, do not take 1 or 10 since in progress, 
but take last first completed clerical of 2,5,7,8,9 (other unoccupied ones) which is 8 (skipping 5 since is not available).

If next assign is technical, it should go to John and if john is not available, should return null.

Wrote something like this so far:

```
function: NextEmployee('Clerical')

Select EmployeeID from Employees e , Activities a where e.available= 1 and e.type='Clerical' and
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. Please also explain the meaning of columns Employees.Available and Activities.Status. Provide sample results table based on the data above.

Comment: employees.available means the employees is available for selection. Activities.status can be complete, which means employee is done with activity and can be selected, or status can be In Progress, which means employee is working on something. for employee to be selectable, employees.available = 1 and activities.status <> 'In Progress'. the text below the table shows an example with expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code uses a [window function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) to find the last activity for each employee and then checks that this activity has 'Complete' status:

```
DECLARE @Type VARCHAR( 20 )
SET @Type = 'Clerical'
SELECT TOP 1 TaskType, EmployeesID, Task_DateTime
FROM(
    SELECT E.EmployeesID, E.TaskType, Task_DateTime, ActivityStatus, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY A.EmployeesID ORDER BY Task_DateTime DESC ) AS LatestEmploeeTask
    FROM #Activities AS A
        INNER JOIN #Employees AS E ON A.EmployeesID = E.EmployeesID
    WHERE Available = 1 ) AS a
WHERE LatestEmploeeTask = 1 AND ActivityStatus = 'Complete'
    AND TaskType = @Type
ORDER BY Task_DateTime ASC
```

I had to convert the sample data into usable table data. The code is below:

```
CREATE TABLE #Employees( EmployeesID INT, UserName VARCHAR( 10 ), TaskType VARCHAR( 20 ), Available BIT )
CREATE TABLE #Activities( ActivityID INT, EmployeesID INT, ActivityStatus VARCHAR( 20 ), Task_DATETIME DATETIME )

INSERT INTO #Employees
VALUES 
( 1, 'Bill', 'Clerical', 1 ),
( 2, 'Ann', 'Clerical', 1 ),
( 3, 'John', 'Technical', 1 ),
( 4, 'Jack', 'Technical', 0 ),
( 5, 'Mary', 'Clerical', 0 ),
( 6, 'Sam', 'Technical', 0 ),
( 7, 'Mark', 'Clerical', 1 ),
( 8, 'Andy', 'Clerical', 1 ),
( 9, 'Rick', 'Clerical', 1 ),
( 10, 'Nancy', 'Clerical', 1 )

INSERT INTO #Activities
VALUES
( 101, 2,    'Complete',    '6/11/2016 10:00'),
( 102, 1,    'Complete',    '6/11/2016 10:12'),
( 103, 3,    'Complete',    '6/11/2016 10:24'),
( 104, 4,    'Complete',    '6/11/2016 10:36'),
( 105, 7,    'Complete',    '6/11/2016 10:48'),
( 106, 6,    'Complete',    '6/11/2016 11:00'),
( 107, 5,    'Complete',    '6/11/2016 11:12'),
( 108, 8,    'Complete',    '6/11/2016 11:24'),
( 109, 10,    'Complete',    '6/11/2016 11:36'),
( 110, 9,    'Complete',    '6/11/2016 11:48'),
( 111, 5,    'Complete',    '6/11/2016 12:00'),
( 112, 8,    'Complete',    '6/11/2016 12:12'),
( 113, 3,    'Complete',    '6/11/2016 12:24'),
( 114, 4,    'Complete',    '6/11/2016 12:36'),
( 115, 1,    'Complete',    '6/11/2016 12:48'),
( 116, 6,    'Complete',    '6/11/2016 13:00'),
( 117, 7,    'Complete',    '6/11/2016 13:12'),
( 118, 2,    'Complete',    '6/11/2016 13:24'),
( 119, 9,    'Complete',    '6/11/2016 13:36'),
( 120, 10,    'In Progress', '6/11/2016 13:48'),
( 121, 1,    'In Progress', '6/11/2016 14:00'),
( 122, 2,    'Complete',    '6/11/2016 14:12'),
( 123, 3,    'Complete',    '6/11/2016 14:24'),
( 124, 4,    'Complete',    '6/11/2016 14:36'),
( 125, 6,    'In Progress', '6/11/2016 14:48')
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good. The only thing I am finding is that if all employees are busy, its returning an employee instead of null. Example if I make John/Technical, employee id 3 busy/In progress, script should return null.